# Difference between "had waited" and "had been waiting"

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

Can I write "I have been waiting for the bus for 30 minutes" instead of "I had waited for the bus for 30 minutes?"

Answer (score 4):

“I have been waiting for the bus for 30 minutes” indicates that you are still presently waiting. “I had waited for the bus for 30 minutes” means that you are no longer waiting – you are on the bus or not.